# Android gradient graphics quality (scaled bitmap)

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I want to display a splash screen with an gradient in my app. But the quality of the gradient in the background is pretty bad. So I create a simple radiant gradient to have a closer look.

Edit: Maybe I should have mentioned that I am using BitmapFactory.createScaledBitmap(); and BitmapFactory.decodeStream() (The graphics are in the assets folder.)

Thats the result:

Original *.jpg (Quality 100%)
[image]

Screenshot Xperia X10 (I took the screenshot with Eclipse)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to scale a bitmap and keep ARGB_8888 I created a new bitmap in the desired size. Then I use canvas to draw the intrinsic bitmap on the new bitmap with `drawBitmap`. This method allows me to scale the bitmap before I draw it on the new bitmap.

```
inputStream = assetManager.open(path);
originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, opts);

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(desiredX, desiredY, Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resizedBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, null, new Rect(0, 0, desiredX, desiredY), null);

inputStream.close();
return resizedBitmap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any jpg file, but using a [shape drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape). Create rectangle and provide necessary parmas for `gradient` tag.

Comment: Thanks, but the bitmap is more complex. I just uploaded this jpeg to have a simple example.

Comment: Then you can do like Skype app - they just draw a lot of drawables for different screens. I can say it was good solution, but it still works :)

Comment: At this rate I will need a lot of drawables. The image I am trying to scale is a background created with photoshop for little game. If it's just a few elements that would be a good solution. But the background is far too complex. And there are some more gradients which aren't radiant or linear.

Comment: It depends on picture, but you can try a little cheat - use one big picture, and center it without any transformations. For small phones only center of picture will be visible

Comment: Pretty unconfortable and unefficient. Actually on some devices I have memory problems already. This cheat seems to need quiet a lot of memory. However, I just found a solution by myself. I will create a Bitmap with ARGB_8888 and draw the desired Bitmap on it using canvas. I will post an example later. Thanks!